# Are all doubt related questions duplicates?

Tags: discussion

Compare [Is it OK to question God about doubts?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/is-it-ok-to-question-god-about-doubts) with an older question https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/438/is-it-okay-to-have-doubts

People are claiming this first is a duplicate of the second. However the first is not asking if it's ok to have doubts, but basically assumes everyone will have doubts and if it's acceptable to bring those doubts to God in prayer.

Seems like two different questions to me (which is why I asked the second!)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple issues going on here.

- The original question was closed as not constructive. Based on the personal content and unclear scope for a correct answer, I agree with this, and discussed it with the OP in chat.
- The new question got closed as a duplicate of a closed question. This should not have happened. Either the new question is also "not constructive" and should have been closed with that reason or it's not actually a duplicate.
- Answers to these questions would not have been interchangeable because the newer question narrowed the scope a LOT by adding a specific path for dealing with doubt and asking whether that path was Biblical, not just any path.

In sum, I support the new question being re-opened. If not a justification should be be presented for why the new question is "not constructive".

Answer (score 1):

Reading both, the one that was closed as a duplicate doesn't seem to actually be a duplicate, especially that was is asking for references, rather than opinion like the first.  if i could i'd vote to reopen.